# Perl regex, avoid unnecessary interpolation

Tags: regex, perl

Consider this example,

```
    $relPath = '..\A\B/C/D/E';
    $contentsDir = '..\A\B';
    $relPath =~ s/$contentsDir//;
    print "$relPath\n";

    #Desired output: '/C/D/E'
    #Actual output: '..\A\B/C/D/E'
```

Please help .. this unwanted interpolation has made it impossible to compute this.

Comment: Try this `s/\Q$contentsDir\E//`

Comment: Or, $contentsDir = `'\.\.\\A\\B'`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote special regex chars with [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) before matching,

```
$contentsDir = quotemeta '..\A\B';
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't mix slashes and backslashes in paths. Use just slashes.
2. If you want to ignore any regular expression characters in a string, place it between `\Q` and `\E` (see documentation in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) or pass it to [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $string = 'abc.*def';
my $sub = '.*';

$string =~ s/c\Q$sub\E/d/;
# or $string = 'c' . quotemeta($sub) . 'd';

print $string;  # abef
```